# Font Face not working on IE10?

Tags: internet-explorer, font-face

I am validating my css for all the browsers, using browserstack to get a preview of each browser.

I was really surprise and angry to discover that my font-faces just don't work on... IE10. 
Everything is just perfect with fonts in ie7, ie8 and ie9.

But now way to have it working on IE10.

Here is the design: 
http://custom-design.ch/_wp/viotrain/template/

Could you check in on a real IE10 browser (not browserstack's one) and tell me: 
-if the problem aslo happen with the real version
-if you have any solution to fix this problem which make me crazy :(

Thank you for your help!
And may all the internet explorer developers die in horrible suffering :D

David

Comment: Note: I used the fontsquirrel font-face generator to implement my fonts .

Answer (score 1):

It works fine for me in IE!0 on Windows 8. Both desktop and Metro UI, for the latoregular and lobsterregular fonts.

Comment: Thank you for your both answers! I finally wrote to browserstack just to be sure and the mistake was due to their version of IE1O!
Everything is fine then!